# Angular - navigate to route or call a controller function based on condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am displaying list of documents in my Ionic app. When user taps on the document and document extension does not end with .autocad, I need to open the document in Cordova InAppBrowser. However, if the extension is .autocad, I need to route to viewer state (where a third party viewer would load the file).

This is how the document list is created in html template

```
</div>
<ion-scroll direction="y" style="{{documentListScrollHeight}}">
  <ion-list ion-list can-swipe="true" show-delete="false">
    <ion-item
              ng-repeat="(docName, format) in folder.Documents"
              class="item item-thumbnail-left" on-tap="openDocInAppBrowser(docName, format)">
      <div class="row">
        <h3>{{docName}}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h4 style="color: #4b4d4e">File Type: {{format}}</h4>
      </div>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-scroll>
</div>
```

When user taps on a document (lets say PDF), right now it calls a function in the controller which open the document in Cordova InAppBrowser. This functionality is working fine.

I need to put a check inside on-tap, so that if the format is .autocad then jump to viewer state instead. Something like

```
on-tap="if(format != 'autocad' {openDocInAppBrowser(docName, format)} else { $state.go('viewer', {docName: docName, format: format })})
```

What is the correct way of doing this in Angular?

Here is how my state is defined

```
.state('viewer', {
  url: '/viewer',
  params: {
    docName: null,
    format: null
  },
  templateUrl: 'templates/viewer.html',
  controller: 'viewerCtrl'
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is correct. Instead of writing the code on tap you may want to incorporate this code in a function
      $scope.check_format = function(docName,format){

if(format != 'autocad' {openDocInAppBrowser(docName, format)} else { $state.go('viewer', {docName: docName, format: format })}

}
and so in the html code ontap=check_format(docName,format)